# What are different Powershell Module Types and what do they mean?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I ran the following command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

and found different module types

- Script
- Manifest
- Binary

[image: powershell modules]

What do the types mean? Can I export some/all of them to use in different powershell in same computer/different computer to use those?

Answer (score 2):

Module types are how the modules or defined. A module is a cmdlet you can run.

---

- **Binary** : Binary modules are cmdlets defined from `exe` or `dll` files compiled from `C#` which is the most common was to make a powershell cmdlet. Custom binary modules are imported by the `import-module` cmdlet.
- **Script** : Script modules are cmdlets defined directly from powershell whether it is a environment defined function or a PS module (`.psm1` file) (`.psxml` files and most other non-`ps1` powershell files are part of script modules.
- **Dynamic** : Dynamic modules are modules defined by the `new-module` cmdlet that are only active to the current scope. Local functions are not considered modules so they don't fall under this either.
- **Manifest** : Manifest modules are modules do not include any powershell code and do not have to be related to powershell at all (i. g. npm). Manifest modules don't fall into any of the other module categories, but also probably can be used without powershell. These can include external `exe`s like `git` and `npm`

---

<sub>For more info check [this link](https://poshland.pro/powershell-module-types-you-should-know/)</sub>